# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException Error

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I'm trying to upload a text file to a sharepoint 2010 site. I'm using the following code:

```
 Using fs As New FileStream(outputfile, FileMode.Open)
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContextLoad, filename, fs, True)
 End Using
```

I'm getting the following error and do not know how to get around it:
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088 
  Message=Unexpected response from the server. The content type of the response is "text/html; charset=utf-8". The status code is "Redirect". 
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint.Client 
StackTrace: 
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinary(ClientContext context, String serverRelativeUrl, Stream stream, String etag, Boolean overwriteIfExists, SaveBinaryCheckMode checkMode) 
     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ClientContext context, String serverRelativeUrl, Stream stream, Boolean overwriteIfExists) 
     at Text_Replacer.Form1.wrk_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SWSPTools\SWSPTools\Editor\Form1.vb:line 502 
     InnerException:

One other piece of info. We are using fedauth so I have to use the following to authenticate and generate the PUT method.

```
 public void ClientContext_ExecutingWebRequestLoad(object sender, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();

        foreach (var c in SharepointTrustCookies)
            cc.Add(c);
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.CookieContainer = cc;
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Method = "PUT";
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8";
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us");
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("Translate", "F");
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
       // e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.ContentLength = line.Length;

    }
```

Here is how I create the clientContextLoad:

```
Dim clientContextLoad As ClientContext = New ClientContext(MY_SITE)
    Dim spAuth As SharepointClaimsAuthentication = New SharepointClaimsAuthentication(MY_USER_NAME, MY_PWD, INTERNAL_AUTH_SITE, EXTERNAL_AUTH_SITE, MY_SITE)
    spAuth.Authenticate()
    AddHandler clientContextLoad.ExecutingWebRequest, AddressOf spAuth.ClientContext_ExecutingWebRequestLoad
    clientContextLoad.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

And here is the filename I am passing:

```
/Team_Documents/Output.txt
```

Comment: What value are you passing in for `filename`? And how are you creating your `clientContextLoad` object?

Comment: filename = "/Team_Documents/Output.txt"

Comment: See the main question for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter `filename` of [`SaveBinaryDirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538285.aspx) should be a **server-relative** url, not site-relative. This means it should include the path of the site, e.g. `/site/subsite/library/filename.txt`

Additionally, you may want to confirm that your `ClientContext` object is being created from the root site of the site collection, not from a subsite.

Comment: I changed the filename as you suggested and verified the ClientContext item. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated